# My php code is not working on postman when i insert parameters

Tags: php, json, postman

Hey guys my php code which is below is not working on postman , Whenever I enter email and password parameter it does not work and shows only one error which is below it shows { success:0 , messsage:invalid request} , I am giving the right parameter from databse , my db table  name is users and columns are id, name , email, password, type. Please check the code I am new in php . pls help

```
    <?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept'); ?>
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT'); ?>
<?php 
 session_start();
include_once('configdb.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$response = array();
if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
$name= $_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'");
 $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
 if($count==1){
    $_SESSION['users']=array(
   'email'=>$row['email'],
   'password'=>$row['password'],
   'name'=>$row['name'],
   'type'=>$row['type']
   );
   $role=$_SESSION['users']['type'];
   //Redirecting User Based on Role
    switch($role){
  case 'user':
 // header('location:user.php');
  $response["success"] = 1;
   $response["message"] = "user.";
  break;
  case 'admin':
 // header('location:admin.php');
  $response["success"] = 1;
   $response["message"] = "admin.";
  break;
 }
 }else{
 $response["success"] = 0;
   $response["message"] = "PASSWORD OR EMAIL DOES NOT EXIST.";
 }
}
else{
$response["success"] = 0;
   $response["message"] = "INVALID REQUEST.";

}
header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($response);
  mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

can you please tell me what is the error?

ALRIGHT HERE IS MY REQUEST [POSTMAN REQUEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU109.png)

Comment: Can you share the request you are making in postman?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `$email` variable in your query, but you saved the password in the `$name` variable.

Comment: thanks , but can you please tell me why this code is only 'user' message not admin ?

Comment: Because the admin probably does not have an email associated? Or it's still saved in the session from a time when the code _was_ working.